# MySQL: index a JSON array column that may contain non-JSON data

Tags: mysql, json

I have a multitenant MySQL 8 DB. Main table is `entity`, it has additional fields (to be configured separately for every tenant): `field1`, `field2` and so on. They can be either text fields, booleans, JSON array etc. A JSON array contains ids/values of multiselect options. For performance, I would like to index this field, however:

```
mysql> alter table entity add index __test_field1((cast(field1 as unsigned array)));
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_array: "Invalid value." at position 0.
mysql> alter table entity add index __test_field1((cast(nullif(field1, '') as unsigned array)));
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_array: "Invalid value." at position 0.
```

As each tenant has `field1` configured with his own type, the actual field can contain text, dates etc. I try to filter out invalid values, but this doesn't work:

```
mysql> alter table entity add index __test_field1((cast(if(json_valid(field1), field1, null) as unsigned array)));
ERROR 3903 (22018): Invalid JSON value for CAST for functional index '__test_field1'.
```

However passing a scalar as a param to `if` does work:

```
mysql> alter table entity add index __test_field1((cast(if(json_valid(field1), '1', null) as unsigned array))); Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.13 sec) Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

This means that the cast accepts the if function, but what comes out of it can still be invalid JSON, even though I've just verified it with `json_valid`.

Is there a way to index such a field?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking on the wrong section

You use secondary indexes to index json, blob and so on.

> JSON columns cannot be indexed directly. To create an index that references such a column indirectly, you can define a generated column that extracts the information that should be indexed, then create an index on the generated column, as shown in this example:

read more https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

After looking into it you main problem ist that you need a valid json for that to wirk

alter table customers add index __test_field1((cast(field1 ->'$.dataforindex'as unsigned array)));

Like in the text before you make an index on a particular value of the json.

The for the new indexes you don't need the generated columns anymore.

the field1 ->'$.dataforindex' has to be in this example an array like [1,2,3,5]

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about the new MySQL 8 feature for indexing JSON arrays: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued

Comment: could you please provide the table and data for the multi-valued Indexes to pöay aroud with .

Comment: like i said this works actually, when you have right datatypes and it only replaces the "old" generated columns index