# MySQL Index Virtual Column of JSON Data When Some Records May have Invalid JSON

Tags: mysql, json

We're running MySQL 5.7.

I have been given a MySQL database with several columns containing JSON data that I need to index.  I've created virtual columns pointing to the data in JSON like so:

```
ALTER TABLE
  listings
ADD COLUMN
  zip VARCHAR(10)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  address_info -> '$.zip'
)
```

However, attempting to create the index with this line:

```
CREATE INDEX zip_idx ON listings (zip);
```

Gives us an error there is invalid JSON in one or more records.

This table was not created by us and finding/fixing the JSON is not possible.  There are millions of records and we don't know how many may have invalid JSON.  Is there a way to create this index and have MySQL simply ignore any record that's invalid?

I realize the following is not possible, but something like:

```
CREATE INDEX zip_idx ON listings (zip)
WHERE JSON_VALID(address_info)
```

Comment: Don't you also get errors whenever you try to use this column in queries? It seems like the index is the least of your problems.

Comment: Yes, but for now, we're able to filter those out using JSON_VALID(address_info) in the WHERE statements.  I guess I'm wanting to know whether creating this index is even possible?

Comment: This is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334013/mysql-index-a-json-array-column-that-may-contain-non-json-data) there's no solution there, either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `JSON_VALID()` in the generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE
  listings
ADD COLUMN
  zip VARCHAR(10)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  IF(JSON_VALID(address_info), address_info ->> '$.zip', '')
)
```

I've also used the unquoting extraction operator so the generated column won't have extra quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this did not work.  Still get Invalid JSON error when trying to create the index.

Comment: @CFMLBread: It works in a basic case, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HCAQZRI).